# How to search in JSON file?

Tags: javascript, php, json

How could I create a search form that will search for the entered term inside a JSON file?

So if the search term is equal to a title inside the location object, it should return that object info. If there is no match, give the user feedback that there are no items found

I created a search input:

```
    <form action="" method="get">               
         <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search term">
         <input type="submit" class="button">
   </form>
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "title":    "Locations",
    "locations":    [
        {
            "title":        "New York",
            "url":          "api/newyork.js"
        },{
            "title":        "Dubai",
            "url":          "api/dubai.js"
        },{
            "title":        "Netherlands",
            "url":          "api/netherlands.js"
        },{
            "title":        "Lanzarote",
            "url":          "api/lanzarote.js"
        },{
            "title":        "Italy",
            "url":          "api/italy.js"
        }

    ]
}
```

Update:

I came up with the following, using jQuery:

```
$("#search").change(function() { 
            var arrival = $(this).val();

            $.getJSON( "api/videoData.js")
            .done(function(data) {
                // update your ui here
                console.dir(data.pages);
                var dataArr = data.pages;

                // Iterate over each element in the array
                for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++){
                    // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
                    if (dataArr[i].title == arrival){
                        // we found it
                        console.log(dataArr[i].title);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Houston, we have a problem');
                    }
                }

            }).fail(function(data) {
            // handle error here
                console.log('no results found');
            });

        });
```

This is working, only it should be entered exactly as stored in the JSON. 
So when you search for "Italy" and you use lowercase type, it will not find the object. Also it will not give any entries when you search for example: `ne`. I would like to get Netherlands and New York as search results.

Comment: have you tried any javascript yourself? If so provide the code

Comment: @depperm, not yet. I don't know how to get the value when the user is click on the submit button, that than will search for that term..

Comment: For lowercase and partial matches just say like: _.startsWith(dataArr[i].title.toLowerCase(), arrival.toLowerCase())

Comment: Why do you pass the search value via the arrivaldate URL parameter? Did you intend to pass a date entered in another input? Could you clarify this in your question?

Comment: Thank you for mention it. I think that should not be part of the code anymore. I remove it out of the code.

Comment: _“So when you search for "Italy" and you use lowercase type, it will not find the object”_ – convert both the search term and the current JSON value you are comparing against to lower case first (using `toLowerCase`.)

Comment: Is there any relation between *pages* and *locations*? Is it one and the same property? The JSON example seems incompatible with your code...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet that demonstrates how the lookup could be done. It only loads the JSON once. I have included the test data for when the JSON request fails, which it will in this demo. At every change of the input value a short list of matches is shown in a `div` below the `input`. The submit button is not included, as the search is immediate.

Try it.

```js
// testData is defined for demo only. Can be removed
var testData = [
    {
        "title":        "New York",
        "url":          "api/newyork.js"
    },{
        "title":        "Dubai",
        "url":          "api/dubai.js"
    },{
        "title":        "Netherlands",
        "url":          "api/netherlands.js"
    },{
        "title":        "Lanzarote",
        "url":          "api/lanzarote.js"
    },{
        "title":        "Italy",
        "url":          "api/italy.js"
    }
];
// Variable to hold the locations
var dataArr = {};
// Load the locations once, on page-load.
$(function() { 
    $.getJSON( "api/videoData.js").done(function(data) {
        window.dataArr = data.pages;
    }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log('no results found');
        window.dataArr = testData; // remove this line in non-demo mode
    });
});
// Respond to any input change, and show first few matches
$("#search").on('keypress keyup change input', function() { 
    var arrival = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#matches').text(!arrival.length ? '' : 
        dataArr.filter(function(place) {
            // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
            return (place.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(arrival) !== -1);
        }).map(function(place) {
            // get titles of matches
            return place.title;
        }).join('\n')); // create one text with a line per matched title
});
// submit button is not needed really
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search term">
<div id="matches" style="height:70px; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:pre"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution has a few steps, let us know which step you can't do:

1. Call a JS function when the user clicks the button
2. Read the file from disk on the server into a JS variable in the browser
3. Use lodash.js to get the url from the JS variable for the search term
4. Display results to the user

---

But taking a stab at the simplest answer, the way I'd do it:

Load your JSON file with the page, like any Javascript file.
Load lodash.js.

Call your JSON file towns.js and make it look like this:

```
var cities = 
{
    "title":    "Locations",
    "locations":    
    [
        {
            "title":        "New York",
            "url":          "api/newyork.js"
        },
        {
            "title":        "Dubai",
            "url":          "api/dubai.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then your HTML is something like this:

```
<input type="" class="button" onclick='go()'>

<script src='towns.js' />
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js' />
<script>
    function go()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById('search').value;
        var result = _.find(cities.locations, {'title': name});
        if (!result)
            window.alert('Nothing found');
        else
            window.alert('Go to ' + result.url);
    }
<script>
```

Comment: I update a second ago also my answer, maybe you can help me with that. I will try your code now!

Answer (score 1):

If you intend your json file as static and not very huge one then you better load it at once on page load event(preventing sending the same requests dozens of times). Try this approach:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        locations = {};

xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xhr.open('GET', 'locations.json', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
        var content = JSON.parse(this.response),
                locations_arr, i, count, title;

        locations_arr = content['locations'];
        for (i = 0, count = locations_arr.length; i < count; i++) {
            title = locations_arr[i]['title'].toLowerCase();
            locations[title] = locations_arr[i];
        }
        console.log(locations);
    }

};
xhr.send(null);
```

Add some identifier to your form element (`id="myForm"`) and 'name' attribute to your input field (`name="search"`);

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() {
    var search_value = this.search.value.trim().toLowercase();
    if (search_value && location[search_value]) {
       console.log(location[search_value]);
    } else {
       alert("Object with specified title not found!");
    }
    // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your update with this code:

> So when you search for "Italy" and you use lowercase type, it will not find the object. Also it will not give any entries when you search for example: ne. I would like to get Netherlands and New York as search results.

$("#search").change(function() { 
            var arrival = $(this).val();

```
        $.getJSON( "api/videoData.js", { arrivalDate: arrival })
        .done(function(data) {
            // update your ui here
            console.dir(data.pages);
            var dataArr = data.pages;

            // Iterate over each element in the array
            for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++){
                // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
                if (dataArr[i].title == arrival){
                    // we found it
                    console.log(dataArr[i].title);
                } else {
                    console.log('Houston, we have a problem');
                }
            }

        }).fail(function(data) {
        // handle error here
            console.log('no results found');
        });

    });
```

Replace this line:

```
if (dataArr[i].title == arrival){
```

for

```
if (dataArr[i].title.toLowerCase().contains(arrival.toLowerCase())){
```

And now it will match all the string that contains the string that you are searching...

Comment: Which line should I replace with your modified code?