# Auto-complete input from json file in JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, autocomplete

I have a JSON file which I want to use to fill in an auto-complete dynamic menu. I want to append this through className since the input texts are dynamic.

Sample json data in the file(.json) is as below:

```
[
  {"Id":"1", "CountryId":"201", "DailingCode":"196", "countryName":"SUDAN", "City":"khartoum", "Code":"KRT"},
  {"Id":"2", "CountryId":"110", "DailingCode":"+254", "countryName":"KENYA", "City":"Nairobi", "Code":"NBO"},
  {"Id":"3", "CountryId":"196", "DailingCode":"+252", "countryName":"SOMALIA", "City":"Mogadishu", "Code":"MGQ"},
  {"Id":"4", "CountryId":"68", "DailingCode":"+251", "countryName":"ETHIOPIA", "City":"Addis Ababa", "Code":"ADD"},
  {"Id":"5", "CountryId":"59", "DailingCode":"+253", "countryName":"DJIBOUTI", "City":"DJIBOUTI", "Code":"JIB"},
  //and so on
]
```

I want to be able bind them to any input texts with `SearchPlaces` class with auto-complete. The user should be able to search with `City` or `Code`.

So far I have tried the code below which works fine for `input select`. I could combine this with [select2JS](https://select2.org/) but the better option would be to use input text with auto-complete.

```
function GetPlaces() {


        let dropdown = $('.SearchPlaces');

        dropdown.empty();

        dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Search...</option>');
        dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

        const url = './Places.json';

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
                dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.code).text(entry.City));
            })
        });
    }
```

I aslo applied [select2JS](https://select2.org/) for searching.

```
//Searchable Dropdown List
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.SearchPlaces').select2();
     });
```

One other problem with the above code is that when the user selects City from the seacrh, the result is all the Cities in the `Json File`.

Can someone help me with is or give me a direction of how/where to go about it?

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255181/how-to-search-in-json-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823022/search-input-field-to-search-json-data) questions here. They were the closet resource I have come across, but I could not get anything from them.

Edit:

In simple terms, I want to use the content of the `.json file` in any input text type having the `SearchPlaces` class using JavScript/jQuery. The search Params are  `City` & `Code` and the displayed search option(auto-complete as the user types) is `City` which will be set as the text after the user selects one from the search options.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I simply want to use tye content of that `.json file`  in  auto-complete(search) input text type using Javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Select2](https://select2.org/) is a good choice for this because you have more complex matching criteria - the user should be able to search by city name or code.

Select2 [has support](https://select2.org/searching) for you providing a custom matcher.

However, before you can write a custom matcher, you will need to ensure you are setting each option's `value` correctly. You haven't upper-cased `code`. It should be:

```
dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.Code).text(entry.City));
```

With that fixed, we can create our custom matcher:

```
$('.SearchPlaces').select2({
  matcher: function(params, data) {
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
    }

    const term = params.term.toLowerCase();

    // data.text corresponds to the text content of the <option>
    if (data.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1) {
      return data;
    }

    // data.id corresponds to the value of the <option>
    if (data.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1) {
      return data;
    }

    return null;
  }
);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/08x9e436/) is a fiddle for reference.

Comment: I'm opting for input text just to avoid displaying Cities for user starts typing in. I want to start dispalaying them as the user types. also what about when the user selects option from the search list, not usre why but I'm geting error/empty.  also what about setting the innerText of `SearchPlaces` when user selects option? I want to retrive it later with `.text()` (jquery). now I get all the Cities in the file.

Comment: @Cabdi: You could update the custom matcher to return no results when the user hasn't typed anything (https://jsfiddle.net/76484/08x9e436/). If you are using a `[type="text"]` input, are you planning on writing all of the dropdown logic yourself? That sounds like a lot of work. You can get the current value with `$('.SearchPlaces').val()`.

Comment: @Cabdi `.val()` should work, but if you have multiple selects, then you will need to target the one you are after. In this code example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/08x9e436/ - I loop over both selects and log the value of each (which is the ID of each selected city).

Comment: Thanks for the update man, I really appreciate it. I want the text, not the values, I will try to figure it out, maybe have another function to update the text, which I think will probably interfering the loaded results.

Comment: @Cabdi: select2 has a `data` method for getting the selected item object, which includes the `id` and `text`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/08x9e436/

Comment: I mean the select tags have a **unque class/name/id** alongside the common class like `<select class="SearchPlaces inputSelect1"></select>`. Can I use one of these to get the text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252238/discussion-between-cabdi-and-76484).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @76484, Here Goes My final solution.

```
 <select class="SearchPlaces place1" id="place1" name="place1"></select>

 <select class="SearchPlaces place2" id="place2" name="place2"></select>


 <button id="btnGetSelectedPlaces" type="button">Log current value</button>



function GetPlaces() {
        //console.log('GetRoutes()');

        let dropdown = $('.SearchPlaces');

        dropdown.empty();

        dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Search...</option>');
        dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

        const url = './Places.json'; //json file directory

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
                dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.code).text(entry.name));
            })
        });
    }
```

Call `GetPlaces()` where you need (`Document.ready` and in `AddPlace` button click event in my case)

I also changed the **the custom matcher** into function since I wanted to use it in the dynamically added selects as well.

```
function GetPlacesCustomMatcher(){
// Custom matcher
    $(function () {
        $('.Route').select2({
            matcher: function (params, data) {
                if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
                    return null;
                }

                const term = params.term.toLowerCase();

                if (data.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1) {
                    return data;
                }

                if (data.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1) {
                    return data;
                }

                return null;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

To get the selected options

```
 $('#btnGetSelectedPlaces').on('click', function(){
      var Val1 = $("#place1").val();
      var text1 = $("#place1").select2('data')[0].text;

      var text2 = $("#place2").val();
      var Val2 = $("#place2").select2('data')[0].text;

      console.log('place 1 value : '+Val1+', place 1 text : '+text1 );
      console.log('place 2 value : '+Val2+', place  text : '+);
 });
```

here I used the `id`s to get the value & text, you can use the `class` or  `name` attributes as well or you can loop them through if you have multiple selects tags

also **Note** ``inex[0] in getting the text, I noticed  that everytime you change the selected option, the text continues to append in an array like and the current selected option text is alway at `index[0]`